# How to read microstackshots file?

Tags: ios, logs, macos

In the root folder of the sysdiagnose logs analytic data there is a specific file named "microstackshots".
Have someone tried to investigate its content? I could not find a way to execute/read it.
If I extract it the result is a microstackshot.out file which seems to be executable on Apple OS.

[Here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20140237219A1/en) a description of what it is about.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According to `man spindump` you should be able to do something like `spindump -i microstackshots.out`. I also had to provide -microstackshots as an argument. Here is the manpage excerpt:

```
-i path Read in the file located at path rather than sampling the live system. Supported file formats are:

    * Spindump text files containing a spindump binary format
    * Spindump text files without a spindump binaty format written in timeline mode (with limited options, and only callstacks will be updated; summary information will not change)
    * Tailspin files
    * Concatenated kcdata stackshots
    * Concatenated microstackshots
```

I did the following to extract the file and get some analysis:

```
mv microstackshots microstackshots.gz
gunzip microstackshots.gz
spindump -microstackshots -i ./microstackshots
spindump -microstackshots_io -i ./microstackshots
```

The manpage has info about which `-microstackshots` arguments you can provide and what each one outputs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/331794)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was inspecting the spindump command on macOS and it contains, as you said, the -i and -microstackshots arguments. I am not able to use them though, since my microstackshots file (which you can find in a sysdiagnose extraction from iOS devices) is in binary format and those arguments allows you to take shots of the current host machine, not an external file. I was looking for some way to be readable. Did I well explained the issue?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how I extracted and used the file with spindump.